# Break string based on a character in VBA 2010

Tags: vba, excel, substr

In Excel 2010, using VBA, how can I breakapart a string when it finds a certain character?

Let say `A1` = `"This is a | test of | the | emergency broadcast signal"`
And I assign that to a variable like

```
strColumnA = Range("A" & CStr(currRow)).Value
```

Now I want to append 4 new rows at the end of worksheet 2. All Column A, like:

```
A1 = "This is a"
A2 = "test of"
A3 = "the"
A4 = "emergency broadcast signal"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use this as there is no need for a loop, also it is important to leave the `Application.Trim()` in:

```
Sub test()

    Dim r As Variant, s As String
    s = [a1].Value
    r = Split(Application.Trim(s), "|")

    [b1].Resize(UBound(r, 1) + 1) = Application.Transpose(r)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Split()`

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Ret
    Dim strColumnA As String
    Dim i As Long

    strColumnA = "This is a | test of | the | emergency broadcast signal"
    Ret = Split(strColumnA, "|")

    For i = LBound(Ret) To UBound(Ret)
        Debug.Print Ret(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```