# Getting the Nth instance of an element

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column filled with data that has a path. I'd like to get the last element in the path, the second last element, and the first element. For example, for the following data:

```
\Product\Release\Iteration
\Product\Folder1\Folder2\Anotherfolder\Release2\Iteration5
\Product
\Product\Somefolder\Release3\Iteration5
```

I'd like to get the following in cells

In cell B1: "Product", cell C1: "Release", cell D1: "Iteration"

In cell B2: "Product", cell C2: "Release2", cell D2: "Iteration5"

In cell B3: "Product", cell C3: blank, cell D3: blank

In cell B4: "Product", cell C4: "Release3", cell D4: "Iteration5"

Getting the first and the last component is easy. I'm mostly just struggling with getting the second to last component (column C in the example above).

Comment: Please post the code or formulas you are using to get the first and last part.

Comment: You could use a macro to split it into a string array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In B1 and copied down:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",REPT(" ",99)),99,99))
```

In C1 and copied down:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",""))=2,TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",REPT(" ",99)),99)),IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",""))>2,TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",REPT(" ",99)),198),99)),""))
```

In D1 and copied down:

```
=IF(OR(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",""))={1,2}),"",TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",REPT(" ",99)),99)))
```

Comment: This works like a gem but has one issue. For
    \Product\Release1

it results in cell B1 having "Product" and cell C1 being blank, cell D1 having "Release1".

Comment: The reason for that is because there is no 2nd to last value in that particular example.  There is simply a first and a last, which is why only cells B and D get populated.  That being said, what would be your preferred results for that example?

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I would prefer if the blank cell is always at the end so cell C1 should say "Release1" and cell D1 should be blank. If that's doable it would be ideal. If not, your solution still wins. Very elegant.

Comment: I have edited my answer to compensate, it should now produce results as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is in ColumnA use Text to Columns with `\` as delimiter to split across columns B:G. Assuming a maximum of 8 elements, put =B1 in K1 and in L1:

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(D1),ISBLANK(C1)),"",IF(ISBLANK($D1),$C1,IF(ISBLANK(C1),"",INDIRECT("R"&ROW()&"C"&COLUMN()-COUNTBLANK($B1:$I1)-4,0))))
```

Copy L1 to M1 and K1:M1 down to suit.

Copy Paste Special Values over the top and delete columns A:I.

Answer (score 1):

Made up two formulas to retrieve any part of the path you want:

Taking the first as starting from the left:

```
=IFERROR(MID(A3,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A3,"\",CHAR(1),C$2))+1,IFERROR(FIND("\",A3,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A3,"\",CHAR(1),C$2))+1)-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A3,"\",CHAR(1),C$2))-1,LEN(A3))),"")
```

Taking the first as starting from the right:

```
=IFERROR(MID(A3,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A3,"\",CHAR(1),LEN(A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3,"\",""))+1-D$2))+1,IFERROR(FIND("\",A3,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A3,"\",CHAR(1),LEN(A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3,"\",""))+1-D$2))+1)-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A3,"\",CHAR(1),LEN(A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3,"\",""))+1-D$2))-1,LEN(A3))),"")
```

And [here's a google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Am9GG-rwdOL1dE92ZGNTYXFzaEN1bnB3c2tSSlMyOHc#gid=0) where you can see how it's working.

Note: I had to make a few changes to the formulae to make it google-spreadsheet-compatible, namely:

- Change `CHAR(1)` to something else, I used `"/"` as substitute
- Add an `IF()` to check for `SUBSTITUTE(,,,0)` (the `0` parameter) since this gives an error in MS Excel but not on google spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to parse the data to cells, you could import a text file into Excel with '\' delimitor.  Otherwise, you need to loop through with CHARINDEX() and SUBSTRING to find the position of each backslash and parse out the data in between.

You could also use SSIS and set up a text file transformation with '\' delimitor to Excel for automation. With TSQL, you need to loop as I suggested

Comment: Good luck... tried to dig up an example but could not fine one.

Answer (score 0):

This has an excellent example that uses the split command.  You just need to change the `|` character to `\` and use the loop to put the individual values in the places you want.

[Break string based on a character in VBA 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099651/break-string-based-on-a-character-in-vba-2010)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you (assuming you don't use * in your file names which I don't think is allowed in windows anyways):

```
=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"\","*",(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"\","")))-1),1))
```

That is for the second last element.

You can get any element you want by changing the bold number:

=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"\","*",(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"\","")))-**3**),1))

**EDIT/ADDITION**

If you want to get rid of the values to the right of the nth element in the formulas above, you can do it like this:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"\","*",(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"\","")))-1),1)),FIND("\",RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"\","*",(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"\","")))-1),1)),1)-1),"error checking, lol")
```

Comment: This doesn't split the different elements into their own cells.  It also doesn't ignore in-between elements so if there are elements between the first one and the last two this will return incorrect results.  Lastly, there is no error checking, so that if an invalid -X is provided where you have shown bolded, it will return a #VALUE! error.

Comment: @tigeravatar Error checking lol. If he is trying to split them into separate cells wouldn't it be better to just do the import wizard and set the delimeter to "\"?

Comment: He is only looking for the first element and the last two.  Using text to columns or the text import wizard won't put the last two elements in the same column for every row of data.  In this case, a formula or VBA solution is preferred to get consistent results for the desired output.

Comment: @tigeravatar is correct. Also I don't want to delimit the values. I have a pivot table that's running a query and pulling a path. I then have columns next to it that I need to extract the first, second to last, and the last elements in the path.

Comment: @tigeravatar See my edit. My assumption was that he already knew how to get the first and last elements - he just needed to know how to get the middle ones - specifically the second last one.